# Accessing JSON on Google Spreadsheet using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-sheets

Hello everybody I hope the description of the problem will be right:

I had create a Google sheet and shared it to access to the JSON file through jquery, the result is:

```
     var $url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1eyzMLOARApWp9phgQkjLChYdVNaipuPJmdbg84MKXLg/od6/public/basic?alt=json';
$.getJSON($url,function(data){
 var obj = JSON.parse(data.feed.entry);
    console.log(obj);
});
```

I can access till the `data.feed.entry.content.$t` but inside this I would like to select the urltorecord, but I can't find the way to select it.

Anybody can help? I'm not sure if the problem is with the Jquery code or the JSON structure.

If I have put this question in the wrong place let me know to move it.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be calling `JSON.parse()`.  Try this:

```
var url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1eyzMLOARApWp9phgQkjLChYdVNaipuPJmdbg84MKXLg/od6/public/basic?alt=json';
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
    console.log(data.feed.entry);
});
```

Because `data.feed.entry` returns an array, you'll need to loop through the array to get the appropriate `$t` values:

```
var url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1eyzMLOARApWp9phgQkjLChYdVNaipuPJmdbg84MKXLg/od6/public/basic?alt=json';
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
  var entries = data.feed.entry;
  for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
    console.log(entries[i].content.$t);
  }
});
```

Comment: First Thanks, second If I want to use the values that I get on the loop do you suggest to save it into an array? and after I can access easily to this information.

Comment: @AntonioA Yes, eso es exactamente lo que sugeriría ;) También sugiero [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), que imagino lo vas a necesitar.

Comment: Thank you very much @Diego I could solve the question with your help, I wish you the best.

Comment: @AntonioA Glad I could help. Please consider marking the question as answered.